# JasperReports API: How to define Data Adapter

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have setup a report in JasperStudio that should receive both report title and query as parameters and then fill the report.

Using the default query value the report is correctly filled from Jasper Studio. I have defined a data adapter (DB.xml) that allows the correct behavior through Jaspersoft Studio.

If I try to fill the report from Java, using something like

```
JasperFillManager.fillReport(fileIn, parameters, new JREmptyDataSource());
```

Where parameters hold both strings for title and query, the pdf exported will have the correct title but no information on the columns, which seems to indicate that the fillReport is not aware of the BD adapter.

Do I have to pass it along the other params? Should I place the adapter xml file anywhere specific?

Comment: `Do I have to pass it along the other params? Should I place the adapter xml file anywhere specific?` - Is your question about using JasperReports API (Java code)?

Comment: @AlexK yes it is !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the data adapter outside JSS, you'll have to set the net.sf.jasperreports.data.adapter property in the report to a file system path or classpath resource where the data adapter xml is located.

And you should not pass a data source when filling the report, use the fillReport method that only takes the report and parameters map as argument.

Comment: I received a warning that the SQLConnection I am passing is null and the report came out empty. The solution I found is to create the Connection and pass it as Data Source, then the report comes out correctly filled.